# Disable prime-ng button based on a value in Local Storage

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to enable/disable buttons based on a user role in local storage.

I have a value in local storage like this Key: Role, Value: "HR Admin"

My HTML looks like this

```
  <button class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']"  > Dashboard </button>
  <button  class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/admin/templates-dashboard']"  > Templates </button>
```

My TS file looks like this and this function fires onInit

```
  const userRole = localStorage.getItem('role');
  if(userRole === 'System Admin') {
    disabled() == false
  } else if (userRole === 'CAT Manager') {
    disabled() == false
  } else if (userRole === 'HR Admin') {
    disabled() == true
  } else {
    disabled() == false
  }
```

Any ideas how this should be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Try this i hope its work for you.

```
 <button class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" [disabled]="buttonDisabled"> Dashboard </button>
 <button  class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/admin/templates-dashboard']" [disabled]="buttonDisabled"> Templates </button>

   const userRole = localStorage.getItem('role');
  if(userRole === 'System Admin') {
    this.buttonDisabled = false;
  } else if (userRole === 'CAT Manager') {
    this.buttonDisabled = false;
  } else if (userRole === 'HR Admin') {
    this.buttonDisabled = true;
  } else {
    this.buttonDisabled = false;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `[disabled]` property to enable or disable button based on value,

**Ts File:**

```
const userRole = localStorage.getItem('role');
```

**HTML File:**

```
<button class="nav-link-btn" [routerLink]="['/dashboard']" [disabled]="userRole === 'HR Admin'"> Dashboard </button>
```